# Elixir Iterate over a list and append values from it to a new list

Tags: elixir

I need to parse some values from a list then recalculate them to a new one, how can that be done in `elixir`?

```
def calc_points(hand) do
    value = []
    
        for i <- hand do
            var = String.at(i,0)
            {val,_} = Integer.parse(var)
            value = [val| value]
            puts(Enum.sum(value))
        end
end
```

Where `hand` is `["6 of spades", "6 of suites"]`
Result should return a new `list` where the first characters of `string` are `integers`

Comment: Hi @Kristjan, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you update your question with some more information on what this function should return? Some score/points or a list of parsed hands? Take a look at [`Enum.map`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#map/2) and try to break down your problem into smaller problems, like: parse every hand to a tuple `{rank, suit}`, use those parsed hands to check for pairs, triples, quads etc. (Assuming a poker game here)

Answer (score 5):

It is helpful if your question includes sample input and desired output.

In Elixir, you will hear that "everything is an assignment".  What that means is that you can't do the standard object-oriented thing and initiate a value up top and then modify it from within a loop.  Instead, you need to rely on the building-blocks of functional programming: map and reduce.

The question you need to ask is whether or not the resulting list has the same number of elements as the incoming list.  If so, then [Enum.map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) should be used to "transform" the elements of the list.  E.g.

```
iex> hand = ["6 of spades", "8 of hearts", "4 of diamonds"]
iex> Enum.map(hand, fn <<first_char::binary-size(1)>> <> _ -> String.to_integer(first_char) end)
[6, 8, 4]
```

Note that the above example grabs the first character of the string by specifying `::binary-size(1)` after the variable name.  This won't work if your `hand` contains strings like `12 of hearts` or `K of diamonds`, the former because it's 2 chars, the latter because a letter won't convert to an integer.

If the resulting list will have a *different* number of elements as the incoming list, then you will likely use [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3).

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will go and look into reduce and map!